# cudaMemcpyToArray

Tags: cuda, cuda-arrays

I seem to have an issue with the function cudaMemcpyToArray. I have the following commands:

```
float *h_data = new float[bmp.width * bmp.height];
...
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
cudaArray *cuArray;
cudaMallocArray(&cuArray, &channelDesc, bmp.width, bmp.height);
cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray, 0, 0, h_data, bmp.width * bmp.height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

As far as I understand, this should give me a 2D array in cuArray that has dimensions bmp.width by bmp.height from the data in h_data, which is a 1D array with dimensions bmp.width * bmp.height. Unfortunately, it just seg-faults on the last command. Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: I don't think this would cause a seg fault, but I believe you want to multiply width and height by sizeof(float), since that param asks for the number of bytes.

Comment: You are correct, there should be a sizeof(float) there. Unfortunately, you are also correct in that this is not the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: It is recommended to use `cudaChannelDesc<float>()` instead of `cudaCreateChannelDesc(32,0,0,0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat)`, to avoid confusion about the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @lmortenson was on the right track, but we don't multiply width *and* height by `sizeof(float)`, just one of them.

1. You need to make sure that your `bmp.width` and `bmp.height` parameters conform to the limits specified [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g04a7553c90322aef32f8544d5c356a10) under `Valid extents`.  These extents are in elements, not bytes.
2. You need to pass width and height parameters to [cudaMallocArray](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g6c5308ef1b088989cbf8a7500918584e) that are in elements, not bytes.
3. You need to pass an overall size parameter to [cudaMemcpyToArray](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g8bb7cc359d74e394138d980e340ccbe4) that is in bytes, not elements, but this would generally be of the form `width*height*sizeof(float)`

I created a simple reproducer based on your code and was able to reproduce the seg fault.  The following code was my adaptation with the errors fixed, I believe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

int main(){
  int width = 256;
  int height = 256;
  float *h_data = new float[width * height];
  cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
  cudaArray *cArray;
  cudaMallocArray(&cArray, &channelDesc, width, height, cudaArrayDefault);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMallocArray");
  cudaMemcpyToArray(cArray, 0, 0, h_data, width*height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToArray");
  return 0;
}
```